# Why I can't send my request with headers? "Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https

This question bother me for a long time. When I send my request to a remote server with 'Jquery' $.ajax() method. I can't add headers in the request, The web server return following  error messeage:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ap3.ragic.com/haisann/forms2/5?api=true' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 
        
GET https://ap3.ragic.com/haisann/forms2/5?api=true net::ERR_FAILED
```

[the error messeage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yurbZ.png)

### This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>js test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="hello()"><a>get data</datagrid></a></button>
</body>
<script>
    function hello(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://ap3.ragic.com/haisann/forms2/5?api=true',
            method:'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers:{
                'Authorization':'Basic MY_API_KEY_HERE'<!--sorry,I can't show my api key-->
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("get data sucess");
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    };
</script>
</html>
```

when i try to remove headers, it works, But the data that the server return is not what i expected, it returns an empty json. I paste the messeage in following block

```
get data sucess
{}
```

### Why python can work?

But it's very strange, When i use python to send the request. **It work perfectly(with headers)**. So i thought that there is might be some mistake in my code

Comment: Browsers enforce certain security restrictions. This includes which headers you can set in a request. (Also, you often need to be serving the page using `https://` as, again for security, many features are unavailable to pages served with `file://` or `http://`.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try other method. Is there any recommended workaround?